# Как прервать цикл при отсутствии нужного файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Мне нужно прочитать из разных файлов в одной папке. Каждый файл это запись сигнала на 1024 отсчета. Я записывал сигналы при усилении от -20 до 30 дБ с шагом 5 дБ, и соответственно давал новые имена каждому файлу. Проблема в том что записанных сигналов при одном уровне усиления может разное количество. Например при -20дБ у меня записано 237 файлов, а при -15дБ 180 файлов. Т.е. в одной папке находятся файлы с разными именами по типу:

- QPSK_-20dB_1;
- QPSK_-20dB_2;
- ...
- QPSK_-20dB_237;
- QPSK_-18dB_1;
- QPSK_-18dB_2;
- ...
- QPSK_-18dB_180;

и т.д.

Как я могу задать условия в цикле, чтобы он прерывался, когда проверит все файлы?

```
col1 = []
col2 = []
col3 = []
y = 0
for k in range(-20,30,2):
    q = 1
    while True: # Как правильно будет записать условия для этого цикла?
        with open(r'C:\Users\Пётр\Documents\LabVIEW Data\8APSK\8APSK_{dB}dB_{num}.lvm'.format(dB=k, num=q), 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                first, second, third = line.split()
                col1.append(first)
                col2.append(second)
                col3.append(third)              
        q += 1
        y += 1
        print(y)
```

Answer (score 3):

почему бы не сделать по другому

1. найти все файлы вида `QPSK_*`

   ```
    import glob, os
    os.chdir("/папка_с_файлами")
    for file in glob.glob("QPSK_*):
   ```
2. у каждого файла распарсить имя и получить нужные параметры

   ```
    prefix, db, id = file_name.split('_')

    db_value = int(db[:-2])
    id_value = int(id)
   ```

и работайте как хотите дальше с файлами - главное что вы все рассмотрите